# Android: how to draw scaled bitmap on canvas?

Tags: android, camera

my goal is to create an app that allows users to take a picture with the camera and then add some images on it just like "face in hole" but reversed.

I'm already capable of showing the camera preview while display a imageview, but when i take the picture  it has a different resolution so the bitmap over the photo is misplaced.

I've wrote this code but it isn't very accurate:

```
        canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null); //drawing the picture just taken on the canvas

        float posx, posy, newx,newy;
        RectF r = new RectF();
        i.getImageMatrix().mapRect(r);  // i is the imageview of the bitmap
        posx= r.left;
        posy= r.top;

        newx=(posx*newImage.getWidth())/screenWidth;
        newy = (posy*newImage.getHeight())/screenHeight;

       canvas.drawBitmap( ((BitmapDrawable)i.getDrawable()).getBitmap(),newx,newy,null);
```

My question is: there's a better and more accurate way to place a bitmap on the picture with the new resolution keeping bitmap scale and rotation info?

Thanks in advance.